# ASP.NET Core HotChocolate schema stitching error

Tags: .net-core, graphql, apollo-client

Facing issues with schema stitching when using HotChocolate. Trying to stitch 2 remote graphql api's, both the remote GraphQL are developed using GraphQL dotnet and stitching gateway api is deployed using HotChocolate. The problem is with Mutation. It works great in the Playground. But when executing the same mutation from Angular Apollo Client code it throws error.

Here is my InputObjectGraphType. I use same input type for both create and update.

```
 public ProfileInputType()
        {
            Name = "ProfileInputType";
            Field(x => x.Id, nullable: true);
            Field(x => x.Name);
            Field(x => x.Description);
            Field(x => x.CreatedBy);
            Field(x => x.UpdatedBy, nullable: true);
       }
```

{"errors":[{"message":"Unexpected Execution Error","locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"path":["updateProfData"],"extensions":{"message":"Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).","stackTrace":"   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()\r\n   at HotChocolate.Stitching.Utilities.HttpQueryClient.FetchInternalAsync(HttpContent requestContent, HttpClient httpClient)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Stitching.Utilities.HttpQueryClient.FetchAsync(IReadOnlyQueryRequest request, HttpContent requestContent, HttpClient httpClient, IEnumerable\u00601 interceptors, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Stitching.Utilities.HttpQueryClient.FetchAsync(IReadOnlyQueryRequest request, HttpClient httpClient, IEnumerable\u00601 interceptors, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Stitching.Delegation.RemoteQueryMiddleware.InvokeAsync(IQueryContext context)","code":"STITCHING_HTTP_REQUEST_EXCEPTION","remote":"HotChocolate.Error","schemaName":"userprof"}}],"data":{"updateProfData":null}}

Any pointers would be much appreciated.